# Query not getting current date result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting data from table for certain date range, but the query not getting data for today's date. Why does this happen?

```
select * 
from mytable 
where action_date >= to_date('01/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
and action_date <= to_date('22/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Result is not showing `22/07/2015` data.

**Edit:**

```
ACTION_DATE TIMESTAMP(6)
```

Sample date in that column :

> 22/07/15 12:47:18.000000000 PM

Comment: What's the datatype for `action_date`?

Comment: What is the datatype of te column? Is it including a timestamp? show sample data please.

Comment: 22/07/2015 will be 22/07/2015 00:00:00 i guess

Comment: @Jens please check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the query by this way, its working as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE action_date                                                    >= to_date('01/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND TRUNC(to_date(TO_CHAR(action_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')) <= TRUNC(to_date('22/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the time part:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where action_date >= to_date('01/07/2015 00:00:00,000000000', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF9') 
and action_date <= to_date('22/07/2015 23:59:00,999999999', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF9');
```

If you only give the date part, the time part is automatically added with the actual time, so if the time part is later you do not get the row.

Comment: hope you understand, no personal on this. Because my answer is what iam expecting , but i upvoted your answer because you explained the reason why that behaves like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
to_date('22/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

this will equal to `July, 22 2015 00:00:00`

From Oracle document:

> Oracle Database stores time in 24-hour format—HH:MI:SS. By default,
>   the time in a date field is 00:00:00 A.M. (midnight) if no time
>   portion is entered.

so `action_date <=/>=` will compare the `data+time`.

For the correct result add required `time` to the `date` field.
eg:

```
to_date('22/07/2015 12:56', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are converting to_date in date, that results in 22/2/2015 00:00:00 and your action_date time for 22/7/2015 is with some time appended. you need to convert action_date in date.

```
select * from mytable where cast( action_date >= to_date('01/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and cast( action_date as date) <= to_date('22/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better than the (original) accepted answer, which misses a small period of time after 23:59.

```
select * 
from mytable 
where action_date >= to_date('01/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
and action_date < to_date('22/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1;
```

Or alternatively if you don't like the +1:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where action_date >= to_date('01/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
and action_date < to_date('23/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: i accepted the answer because, Jens given explanation first why the query messing

Comment: Date is the object which is selected from calander object on UI screen. So i can use first query of yours . But i corrected my query and posted too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query.

```
select * 
from mytable 
where trunc(action_date) >= to_date('01/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
and trunc(action_date) <= to_date('22/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

This will perform a date-level comparison rather than one based on the date and exact time.

Comment: This works but I don't think Oracle will be able to use an any index on `action_date`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is to use '< nextday' instead of boring '<= 23:59:59'.

```
select * from mytable
where action_date >= to_date('01/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')    
and action_date < to_date('23/07/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: I don't think using less than would prevent the optimizer from choosing an index range scan if ACTION_DATE had an index.

Comment: @APC Yes, my fault. No matter at all, even partitions should work OK.